# Individually tag instance in Azure VMSS

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

Is it possible to individually tag a specific vm instance in a scale set?

Something like this command:

```
az resource tag --tags "name=hostname.example.com ip=10.0.0.10" --id "/subscriptions/{SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourceGroups/{RESOURCE_GROUP}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/{SCALESET_ID}/{SCALESET_INSTANCE}"
```

`SCALESET_INSTANCE` is what I get when querying the instance metadata service as follows:

```
curl -s -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute/name?api-version=2017-08-01&format=text"
```

However the response I get is:

```
az resource: error: argument --ids: invalid ResourceId value: <FULL_ID_PATH>
```

Tried using:

```
 az resource tag -g {RESOURCE_GROUP} --resource-type "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -n {SCALESET_INSTANCE}
```

But no luck either, response is:

```
The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{SCALESET_INSTANCE} under resource group '{RESOURCE_GROUP}' was not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to individually tag instance in Azure VMSS as there is no resource type for VMSS instance, just for the type of **Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets**.

[image]

About the [az resource tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags#azure-cli) command: `az resource tag --tags vmlist=vm1 --id /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup}/providers/xxxxxxx`, the **--id** is used for using a **resource identifier** which is different from instance metadata service.

Overall, Azure virtual machine scale sets let you create and manage a group of identical, load balanced VMs. It works as an entirety, it seems that we do not need to add the tags for the individual instances.

Comment: Feature request then: 
Support tags for individual machines in a Scaleset.  
  
In AWS for example, an instance in an auto scaling group is exactly the same as any other instance and can be referenced individually by it's instance ID.  
  
Additionally, as shown above, Azure itself has a unique "name" identifier for each instance in a Scaleset, why not just add this as it's resource identifier as well?

Comment: Welcome to vote it, I have posted this feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/36070555-support-tags-for-individual-machines-in-a-scaleset).

Comment: There is actually a resource type for VMSS VM's but it's still impossible. The resource type is `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/virtualMachines`.